# Cant implement Admob rewarded video ads in my app. Cannot create an instance of an abstract class. | RewardedAd()

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, admob, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTkZ3.png)
As you can see I followed google's official documentation, but still it throws error every time. It says cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

Answer (score 4):

On page: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded

you can see the warning:

> Warning: This guide covers the rewarded API as it existed prior to
> 19.7.0. Please read the migration guide for more details on the changes introduced in version 19.7.0 and finalized in 20.0.0.

And you can update the new guide at
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/rewarded/RewardedAd